# How to add resolvers via ansible on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, ansible, ubuntu-16.04

I'm starting on some Ubuntu 14.04 upgrades and creating some Ansible playbooks along the way to be used on several other hosts later on. First off is setting up `/etc/resolv.conf` to point to local DNS resources.

The old method of provisioning `/etc/resolv.conf` was a shell script with awk/sed/grep which ran over `ssh` which edited the file directly. This seems to be a no-no in 16.04 which warns against this with:

`# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
 # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN`.

The man page for `resolvconf` mentions adding `dns-nameservers` into `/etc/network/interfaces` and also a note discouraging the use of `resolvconf` to add nameserver info by hand:

`The administrator can run resolvconf from the command line...but this is not normally necessary or advisable.`

It seems the only option left is to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` but how do I specify the network interface in the playbook? It's not the standard `eth0..1..2` but some mix of alphabet soup like `enp6s0` or `ens18` which I don't quite get. On an different upgrade, I was able to override this odd naming schemed by adding `biosdevname=0` to grub, but this does not seem to have any effect on this new host even after running `update-grub` and rebooting.

Is there some way to tell ansible to find the primary nic and add a nameserver line in `/etc/network/interfaces` for these hosts?  My current non-working playbook is below:

**(updated working example from accepted answer)**

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: setup resolv.conf in DMZ9 for Ubuntu 16.04 hosts
      when: ansible_default_ipv4.address is match("192.1.9")
      when: ansible_distribution_release is match ("xenial")
      interfaces_file:
        iface: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4['interface'] }}" 
        option: dns-nameservers
        value: 192.1.9.4 192.1.9.10
```

Comment: You probably want to look at this question about how to disable interfaces naming scheme  https://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: The network interface names are available in the `ansible_interfaces` fact. Keep in mind that `lo` is also listed in that fact.

Comment: @AlexD Thanks. I added `net.ifnames=0` to grub and now I have `eth0` back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ansible_default_ipv4['interface']` contains the name of the interface. I find running

```
ansible all -i localhost, -m setup -c local
```

helpful to determine what variables ansible defines.

Comment: So like this?: `iface: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4['interface'] }}"`. I've updated the playbook in my question with this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer the playbook part of the question for anyone else stumbling through this -- I ended up removing the resolvconf package by hand and was able to forego any twiddling with `udev` rules. The added `net.ifnames=0` boot arg is puzzling, but apparently necessary, in some contexts, for `ethX` nic naming. I have other 16.04 hosts which were setup months back which do not require this boot arg so something else is apparently involved.